# Finding the optimal sum of integers

Tags: analysis, algorithms

In my problem, I have a pool of 30 integers which is static.  I am trying to solve for the sum of a subset of these integers that gets closest to a target value.

As an abbreviated example, say I have a pool of 8 integers which includes 928, 905, 837, 735, 612, 482, 98, 55.  Using any combination of these numbers (only once per number), what numbers summed up equal the value closest to a target number, say 2,000?

My pool of 30 integers will remain the same, but I will need to solve for approximately 200 different target values this way.

Comment: There are only $2^{30}\approx$ one billion sums to consider, which isn't very many these days, unless you want some way to find the answer(s) without using a computer....

Comment: This problem is known as the knapsack problem. There are several algorithms to solve it. Integer programming, Dynamic programming, etc.

Comment: as @CesarEo said, you should solve it with dynamic programming, sort these values and compare their sums, knapsack them innerly, then start from the minimum sum until you exceed the deadlimit=200.

Comment: Thanks to all.  I'm onto a solution.  Much appreciated.  Very helpful.